# Update facebook using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, json, oauth

I want to send a JSON object to facebook, but only using javascript/ajax i.e client side scripting language

the problem  is how to send the user credentials in the JQuery/JSON twitter/fb API calls.
my user credentials are from facebook OAuth.

Comment: What do you mean by "send a JSON object to facebook"? The [facebook javascript sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) already adds the access token to all api calls and so you don't need to add any *user credentials*.

Comment: JSON object containing parameters to get OAUTH token

Comment: "*I want to send a JSON object to facebook*", try sending them an email. Closing for not being a *real question*. Please put more effort in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you mean by "send a JSON object to facebook" but I'll try to answer what I do understand.

In the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) they include an example of how it's done, go to the section titled *Client-side Flow*.
You can also use the javascript sdk of course, something like:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === "connected") {
        loggedIn();
    }
    else {
        // status is either "not_authorized" or not logged in to facebook
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                loggedIn();
            }
            else {
                // user not logged in or did not authorize the app
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will first check if the user is already logged in and authorized your app, if not will try to.  The code is not tested in anyway, I "glued" it from different examples.
Please read the [documentation of the sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).